# How to determine the exact 'font-family' CSS value of an uploaded TrueType font?

Tags: css, fonts

I have just downloaded KlavikaBold font from the internet and I wish to use it on my website but uploading it on my hosting. I have included the font on the web page but how do I determine its font family and type so I can use it?

Comment: It's sans-serif (to answer the title), see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif. Try http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like FontSquirrel's amazing [webfont generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to build a proper web font package with all the needed formats and style sheets. (Just uploading a TTF somewhere on the web won't do, it is much more complex than that.)

Note that not every font's license agreement allows for embedding as a web font.